# How to remove multiple if-else or repetitive ternary operations?

Tags: c#, .net-core

I want to make the following function using DRY principle.

```
private void DetermineLeftAndRightPoint(Coordinate coordinate1, Coordinate coordinate2)
{
    // If false, then parallel to Y axis
    if (IsParallelToXAxis == true)
    {
        LeftPoint = coordinate1.X < coordinate2.X ? coordinate1 : coordinate2;
        RightPoint = coordinate1.X < coordinate2.X ? coordinate2 : coordinate1;
        return;
    }

    LeftPoint = coordinate1.Y < coordinate2.Y ? coordinate1 : coordinate2;
    RightPoint = coordinate1.Y < coordinate2.Y ? coordinate2 : coordinate1;
}
```

I tried to create another function with 'out' parameters for determining the Left and Right point for when the segment is parallel to X or Y but then again I had to choose the X/Y parameter using if-else. Is there a better way to write the function?

Comment: I don't think there's anything wrong with your code. Trying to abstract it any more is probably going to make it more complicated for no real gain.

Comment: I would get rid of the `return` and add the bottom part into the `else` part of the `if` statement. Makes it more readable and less prone to errors if you later make changes to the function

Comment: Right. But for determining the Left and Right point, I am checking the same condition in the ternary. Is there a way to avoid that?

Comment: Well, obviously you can do the `coordinate1 < coordinate2` once in an `if` and then do both (left and right) assignments based on the result.

Comment: What are `LeftPoint` and `RightPoint`? If they, say, ends of a *line* or something, I suggest *extracting class* (`struct`?) and return the class instance, not `out` parameters.

Comment: Left and Right are the ends of a segment. Overloading the ```<``` operator to determine which point is small or big based on the parallel bool, seems a little beneficial.

Comment: Well, it is making it more complicated as Sean already suggested. I might just keep it that way.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of implementing `out` parameters, `if else` and tirnary operators I suggest extracting a *class* where we can put all corresponding logics:

```
public enum ParallelToAxis {
  None,
  X,
  Y 
}

public class Segment {
  public Segment(Coordinate left, Coordinate right)
    : this(left, right, ParallelToXAxis.None); 

  public Segment(Coordinate left, Coordinate right, ParallelToAxis kind) {
    // Should we swap left and right?
    if (kind == ParallelToAxis.X && left.X > right.X ||
        kind == ParallelToAxis.Y && left.Y > right.Y) {
      Left = right;
      Right = left; 
    }
    else { 
      Left = left;
      Right = right;
    }
  }

  public Coordinate Left {get;}
  public Coordinate Right {get;} 
  ...
  //TODO: Implement Equals, GetHashCode, ToString() etc.  
}
```

Then you can put as easy as

```
private void DetermineLeftAndRightPoint(Coordinate coordinate1, Coordinate coordinate2)
{
    Segment seg = new Segment(
      coordinate1, 
      coordinate2, 
      IsParallelToXAxis ? ParallelToAxis.X | ParallelToAxis.None);

    LeftPoint = seg.Left;
    RightPoint = seg.Right;
}
```

You can go further and get rid of `LeftPoint` and `RightPoint` for single `Segment` property